# How does PHPUnit tests itself?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

There was an interesting question in our team where a colleague asked how PHPUnit ensure that it's logic is tested.

I tried to find any information about that but i was getting flooded with tutorials to PHPUnit as a framework (of course). I found nothing about the technical background or the development process.

Afterwards i tried to find any hints directly in the PHPUnit package. There are tests, but only rudimentary in my opinion.

Does anyone know how the assertions and all the stuff are tested and how it works? Does PHPUnit maybe depend on a previous version of itself?

Thank you in advance for any answer!

Comment: It has it own tests: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tree/master/tests hardly rudimentary (80% coverage, [tests: 1633, assertions: 2891](https://travis-ci.org/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/jobs/332790195#L626)), also it relys on [other components](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/composer.json#L35) which again [have their own tests](https://phpunit.de/build-status.html).

Comment: PHPUnit only collects code coverage while a test is being executed. Which is exactly what you want for testing everything but PHPUnit itself. This means that PHPUnit reports its own code coverage lower than it actually is.